# Laravel "drupal like" taxonomy

Tags: laravel, taxonomy

I need to add taxonomy support to my laravel 5.4 app where i can create vocabularies and terms (similar to drupal way). i found many packages but none of them is working. how to do that?

Comment: Did you try the most common one: https://github.com/DevFactoryCH/taxonomy

Comment: yes. not working. The installtion looks like not for laravel 5.2+

Comment: Then I would create my own structure, you can check one DB schema there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064976/many-to-many-relationships-with-taxonomy-in-eloquent

Comment: looks like i'll end doing my own tagging system. I just wanted to save some time :)